# Python pandas DataFrame Columns and Data passed seem differ in size, but no

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python3.9 and pandas.

I am trying to build a DataFrame, but during execution I get this error:

```
raise ValueError(err) from err
       ValueError: 13 columns passed, passed data had 14 columns
```

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
```

When I do this:

```
df_printers = pd.DataFrame(printers, columns=[
            'id_printer',
            'serial_number',
            'product_number',
            'installation_date',
            'product_full_name',
            'country_code',
            'customer_name',
            'sold_to_customer_name'
            'warranty_ship_to_country_code',
            'warranty_active',
            'warranty_start_date',
            'warranty_end_date',
            'number_active_contracts',
            'number_active_care_packs',
        ])
```

I am trying to build the **DataFrame**, the objects "printers" is a list of printers where the element of the list has 14 fields, and I am passing "columns" that has, again, 14 fields.

But at executing the code I get the error.

[image]

printers is this:

```
printers = []

printers.append([
                        str(serial_number) + "@" + str(product_number),
                        serial_number,
                        product_number,
                        installation_date,
                        product_full_name,
                        country_code,
                        customer_name,
                        sold_to_customer_name,
                        warranty_ship_to_country_code,
                        warranty_active,
                        warranty_start_date,
                        warranty_end_date,
                        number_active_contracts,
                        number_active_care_packs
                    ])
```

As you can see, it has **14 columns/fields**.

I really don't get the error, the number of the columns/fields, in both cases, is 14.

But it's telling me that I am passing elements of 14 and instead defining a DataFrame with 13 columns.

I use a Virtual Environment in Windows and Python 3.9.

---

Variables inspections with PyCharm:
printers is a list of 5 elements.
[image: Printers list]

Let's inspect one element of the list.
It must have **14** columns.

[image: First Element of the list]

Yes! It has **14** columns/field like the DataFrame requires !

so why I get this error ?

Please, before put negative feedback to this question, give me suggestions on how to improve.
Many thanks to everybody.

Comment: Do a `len()` on your list before passing.  What do you get?

Comment: The list could contain 1, 5 or more element, The problem is not the size of the list, it's the size of the "columns" inside the list. I will add an image of what it is contained in printers.

Comment: Can you post a text version of your list?

Comment: Yes, I will post a Text version of the list, but on Monday, now I have to stop wotking :) A positive vote on the question would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a trailing comma in your column list.

```
columns = [
            'id_printer',
            'serial_number',
            'product_number',
            'installation_date',
            'product_full_name',
            'country_code',
            'customer_name',
            'sold_to_customer_name'
            'warranty_ship_to_country_code',
            'warranty_active',
            'warranty_start_date',
            'warranty_end_date',
            'number_active_contracts',
            'number_active_care_packs',
        ]

print(columns)

['id_printer',
 'serial_number',
 'product_number',
 'installation_date',
 'product_full_name',
 'country_code',
 'customer_name',
 'sold_to_customer_namewarranty_ship_to_country_code',
 'warranty_active',
 'warranty_start_date',
 'warranty_end_date',
 'number_active_contracts',
 'number_active_care_packs']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think your issue is you are appending a list to a list, therefore creating a list of lists of length 1, even though you have 14 elements in the nested list.

There are a few ways to handle this. You can go into the list item by list indexing, i.e. `printer[0]`, and access the data you intended.

Another way it can be handled is to use list comprehension to unpack the list when appending. Something like this:

`_ = [printers.append(thing) for thing in someList]`

or

`printers = [thing for thing in someList]`

You may also want to consider creating a separate list variable instead of doing everything inside the append method.

Comment: Hello FilippinBits, no, the problem is not on building the List :) But on passing the list fo the pandas dataframe. Number of columns differ for an element, and I don't get why, if both element, paramenter columns=  and printers, have 14 columns. Can you give me by the way a positive feedback ? Thank you !

Comment: Hi RobyB, I just did another test using `printers = [str(i) for i in range(1,15)]`. Then used `pd.Dataframe(printers, columns=[printers]` and received a ValueError of a different kind. ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14, 1), indices imply (14, 14). This probably doesn't help you so much, but it seems to imply something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for trying ! But the problem is with the DataFrame :)

Comment: No problem! I totally missed the mark on my answer lol but I tried! I'm going to keep poking around, see if I find anything useful. Maybe I can correct my answer ;-P